# Split single column into two in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel body that is holding 4 items. Right now they are stacked right on top of each other, so 1 columns with 4 rows. I would like for it to be 2 columns with 2 rows on each column.

I can not seem to figure out a way to do this.

Markup:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="menu-item blue">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                <a>
                    <%--<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></i>--%>
                    <p>My title</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 1</a></p>
                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 2</a></p>
                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 3</a></p>
                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 4</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap every two items inside the panel-body within [**`col-xs-6`**](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) which is equivalent to `width: 50%`

`col-xs-*` is used to start the grid from extra small devices. You can replace it with `col-sm\md\lg-*`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="menu-item blue">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <a>
        <%--<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></i>--%>
          <p>My title</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 1</a>
        </p>
        <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 2</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 3</a>
        </p>
        <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 4</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="menu-item blue">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                <a>
                    <%--<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></i>--%>
                    <p>My title</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-sm-4">
                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 1</a></p>
                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 2</a></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 3</a></p>
                <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 4</a></p>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the row class:

```
  <div class="row">
       //cols
  </div>
  <div class="row">
       //cols
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bootstrap's grid system` to do that:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="menu-item blue">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center"> <a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></i>
                        <p>My title</p>
                    </a>
    
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 1</a>
                            </p>
                            <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 2</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 3</a>
                            </p>
                            <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test 4</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @JMusic I just updated his code with the `bootstrap grid` layout.

Comment: I see, just informed you in case that u forgot :)